# Java code won't execute after calling a classes function

Tags: java, android

I have created a program that will connect to a database through PHP and echo back a response. My android program then makes a request to the PHP file and reads the echo in.

```
    public class Read_Author extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String authorName = "";


    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/scripts/read_information.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        authorName = String.valueOf(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

        String myStr = "ANSWER";
        Log.v(myStr, authorName);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

    return authorName;

}

public String returnAuthor(){

    return authorName;
}
```

}

I successfully retrieve the echo string and put it in the author name string variable. But when I then try to call return author from my main activity I get no error but the code does not get run.

I call a function called "readValue" within my main activity and within that function, the execute function gets read and then what is supposed to happen is the returnauthor function is supposed to run. But instead, nothing happens
Main Activity Code:

```
    public void returnAuthor(){
    loadAuthor.execute();

    String a = loadAuthor.returnAuthor();
    Log.v("HIT ME", a);
    }
```

If anyone has any suggestion on why this could be happening and how to fix it that will be very much appreciated!

Comment: you have an AsyncTask, you dont need to call no returnAuthor but instead wait until the tast is done and gives back the String result

Comment: what kind of listener can I use for that within the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misconception about `AsyncTask`. The result of `AsyncTask` may not be available instantly, because the background task might not have been completed.

You need to override the method `onPostExecute` in your `AsyncTask` to perform some task after the background task has been completed.

First show a progressDialog before executing the `AsyncTask`

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
```

Then in the `onPostExecute:`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.d("author", result);
}
```

Comment: alright so once I have added the onPostExecute function and the background task is completed the onPostExecute will run and then that's when I should return the string? And then if that is the case what will my main activity code do while the Asynctask is executing in the background? Is there any way I could make the main activity wait until the background executable is done?

Comment: You may not want to freeze your app by waiting for the background task to finish. You must implement the code in `onPostExecute`. This is how callbacks work.

Comment: Alright, I am fairly new to the java environment, I have been trying to add the onPostExecute override but it is not being recognized. Right after the end of doInBackground Function i do:    @Override
    protected String onPostExecute(String Result){

        return Result;
    }       what is it that I am missing, is there something I am just not grasping? Does the onPostExecute have to return a boolean, all I want to do is return the string value once the background process is done! I am being told that the onPostExecute is clashing with the doInBackground executable.

Comment: `onPostExecute` have void return type. check edited answer.

Comment: where is the string being returned to? I haven't specified where to return the string to? Is there a default location, I tried to add String s = loadAuthor.execute but I received red under the code.

Comment: Asynchronous tasks do not have return system. They have callback system. They call your onPostExecute after the background task completes. One thing you can do is run the AsyncTask in the start of your app and store the author in a global variable which you can access directly after sometime.

Comment: Would there be any way for me to add a loading bar to wait until the process is done?